# Check for null columns in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which has more than 200 columns, I want to check if any of the column is having only null/ blank values in the entire table. I tried to do it using

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || STRING_AGG(   'max("'
                               || column_name
                               || '") "'
                               || column_name
                               || '"',
                               ',')
                 || ' FROM <table name>;'
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name='<table name>';
```

From here, it will give me max values of a column, and I understand that columns with values null is what I am looking for, but question is how do I display that. I am using PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: Your query won't work with column names that require quoting, e.g. names in `CamelCase`. What problem do you encounter running the resulting query and checking for NULL values?

Comment: What result are you looking for? All rows of that table that contain at least one null column? All tables that have at least one row with a null value? The names of the columns that are null for all rows?

Comment: sounds like the last option, a_horse_with_no_name, he wants column names with only DBnull / blanks

Answer (score 1):

From the wording of your question, I guess something like:

```
SELECT substr(agg_stmt,1,LENGTH(agg_stmt)-10) FROM (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(stmt, '') as agg_stmt FROM (
        SELECT 'SELECT ' || '''' || column_name 
            || ''' as col, COUNT(NULLIF(' || column_name || ','''')) as cnt FROM ' 
            || table_name || '' || ' union all ' as stmt
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_name = 't'
    ) AS TT
) AS TTT;
```

should do. For a table T (x, y) it will generate a stmt like:

```
SELECT 'x' as col, COUNT(NULLIF(x,'')) as cnt FROM t union all SELECT 'y' as col, COUNT(NULLIF(y,'')) as cnt FROM t
```

You can add an outer stmt like:

```
SELECT col FROM (
    SELECT 'x' as col, COUNT(NULLIF(x,'')) as cnt FROM t 
    union all 
    SELECT 'y' as col, COUNT(NULLIF(y,'')) as cnt FROM t
) AS Q
WHERE cnt = 0
```

to get all columns that have only null or ''

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the names of the columns that contain a NULL value in all rows, you can use a JSON function for that:

```
select x.col as column_name
from null_test t
  cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) as x(col,val) 
group by x.col
having count(x.val) = 0
```

Note that this is extremely inefficient, but has the advantage that you don't need to know the column names of the table.

Online example: https://rextester.com/WOJU64294